# "Error: backward ref to unknown label..." in MinGW inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, inline-assembly

Once again, I play with MinGW inline assembly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foobar(int);

int main(){
 int n = 0;
 printf("Number: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("\n%d",foobar(n));
 return 0;
}

int foobar(int num){
 int result = 0;
 asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n");
 asm("mov eax, num\n");
 asm("add eax, 110b\n");
 asm("sub eax, 2\n");
    asm("mov result, eax\n");
 return result;
}
```

Compile it:

> C:\Users\Andre\Codes>gcc asmtest.c -o asmtest -masm=intel

Ouch, there are errors:

> C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqny4yb.s:
>   Assembler messages:
>   C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqny4yb.s:53:
>   Error: backward ref to unknown label
>   "110:"

What's wrong here? I think my code is valid already?

Comment: If it's unknown, how does it know that it's backward?

Answer (score 1):

GCC works best with AT&T style assembly, and GAS doesn't implement all of Intel syntax.  Your immediate problem comes from `110b` not being interpreted as a number, but that's not all.

You can't reference variables directly in GCC's inline assembler syntax.  You'll have to write it like this (using the default `-masm=att`):

```
int foobar(int num) {
    int result;
    asm("mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        "add $6, %%eax\n\t"
        "sub $2, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %0"
        : "=g" (result)
        : "g" (num)
        : "eax", "cc");
    return result;
}
```

After the first colon is a comma-separated list of output operands.  Because `"=g" (result)`  is the first constraint, `result` gets alias `%0`.  `"=g"` indicates to GCC that `%0` can be any general-purpose register or memory and will only be written to.  (`+` instead of `=` would indicate read-write.  GCC may decide to re-use the same register for multiple purposes, so you must be explicit in telling it exactly how everything will be used.)

After the second colon is a comma-separated list of input operands.  Because `"g" (num)` is the second constraint, `num` gets alias `%1`.  `"g"` means it will only be read from.

After the third colon is a comma-separated list of clobbers.  This tells GCC that the inline-assembly may change these registers/memory even though they're not input nor output, so that GCC must reload any information it was keeping in them across the inline assembly.  Here, we obviously change `%eax`, and the condition code (flags) register is also affected by `add/sub`.

Look at the assembly the compiler generates:

```
$ cc -S -o- -m32 asmtest.c | sed -n /globl.foobar/,/-foobar/p
.globl foobar
        .type   foobar, @function
foobar:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $16, %esp
#APP
# 15 "asmtest.c" 1
        mov 8(%ebp), %eax
        add $6, %eax
        sub $2, %eax
        mov %eax, -4(%ebp)
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        leave
        ret
        .size   foobar, .-foobar
```

The compiler has decided to use the stack locations of `num` and `result` directly.  If we used `:"=r":"r"` constraints (which means only registers are permitted) instead of `:"=g":"g"` (which permits registers or memory locations), the compiler would copy them to/from registers before/after the inline assembly.

```
$ cc -S -o- -m32 asmtest.c | sed -n /globl.foobar/,/-foobar/p
.globl foobar
        .type   foobar, @function
foobar:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
#APP
# 15 "asmtest.c" 1
        mov %edx, %eax
        add $6, %eax
        sub $2, %eax
        mov %eax, %edx
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        movl    %edx, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        leave
        ret
        .size   foobar, .-foobar
```

If you really want to use Intel syntax, put it in a separate `.s` source file, assemble it independently with [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/), then link the objects together.

```
$ cat asmtest.c
#include <stdio.h>

int foobar(int);
/* int foobar(int) __attribute__((fastcall)); */

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", foobar(n));
    return 0;
}
$ cat foobar.s
global foobar
foobar:
        mov eax,[esp+4]  # take this line out if C prototype is marked fastcall
        sub eax,110b
        add eax,2
        ret
$ nasm -f elf foobar.s
$ cc -m32 asmtest.c foobar.o
$ ./a.out
Number: 30
26
```

(Although `-f elf` isn't correct for Windows.  Maybe `-f win32`?  And due to Windows' stupidity, you may have to use the name `_foobar` in assembly.)

Comment: Many thanks. That works. Now I wonder, how GCC know that %0 is an alias for result, and %1 is an alias for num. I still don't get it.

BTW, what do these 3 lines mean?
 : "=g" (result)
 : "g" (num)
 : "eax");

Comment: @anta40 More details added.  But really you should read the whole http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html section of the GCC manual.